# Fetch Date Correctly from mysql database in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Below is the query which i used to fetch my data from mysql database

```
SELECT p.*,CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS proposerUserName,
v.`vessel` AS vesselDepartmentName FROM proposemoc AS p 
LEFT JOIN mocgenerate AS m ON m.id=p.mocId 
AND m.isDeleted=FALSE 
LEFT JOIN `user` AS u ON u.`uuid`=p.proposerName 
LEFT JOIN `vessel` AS v ON v.`vuid`=p.vesselDepartment 
AND v.isDeleted=FALSE WHERE p.mocNo= '2022/VSL/005' 
AND p.isDeleted=FALSE;
```

But When the Above query execute it give following response

```
{
    "id": 22,
    "mocId": 5,
    "mocNo": "2022/VSL/005",
    "OriginatedType": "Vessel",
    "subject": "ssdf",
    "vesselDepartment": "cfab180c-0b90-48f3-97f1-abef6feac723",
    "dateInitiated": "2022-01-26T18:30:00.000Z",
    "proposedCompletionDate": "2022-01-26T18:30:00.000Z",
    "proposerName": "sdf",
    "proposerRank": "sdf",
    "proposedChangesList": [],
    "proposedChangesReason": [],
    "proposedChangesType": [],
    "tempEmergencyChangeFrom": "2022-01-30T18:30:00.000Z",
    "tempEmergencyChangeTo": "2022-01-27T18:30:00.000Z",
    "natureProposedChanges": "sdfsdf",
    "attachmentFile": "",
    "isActive": 1,
    "createdAt": "2022-01-26T17:47:54.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-26T17:47:54.000Z",
    "isDeleted": 0,
    "createdBy": 1,
    "proposerUserName": null,
    "vesselDepartmentName": "Vessel 04",
    "proposedMocAttachments": []
}
```

But the response column **dateInitiated** in above response is fetching one day before the date which is stored in database

I dont know why this happen even my server time is correct but still getting wrong time

Comment: It's (probably) not wrong, it's a UTC timestamp (signified by the "Z" at the end of it).

Comment: @robertklep is there any solution for this so that i get correct date which is stored in database

Comment: If by "correct" you mean "with my server's timezone", then you're probably not using the correct storage type in your database. [Read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) on how MySQL deals with timezones.

Comment: @aru
What is stored in database? What date do you want? And what date are you getting?

Comment: @Hashim the datecolumn is in datetime format, i m getting date-->2022-01-26T18:30:00.000Z and the date stored in my database i-->  2022-01-27 00:00:00

Comment: @arun the timestamp is being converted into UTC time, what module are you using to connect to database? Try passing your timezone while making connection to see if that solves your problem.